# Can someone translate 一陪二十的赌注啊! for me?

Tags: translation

can someone translate this for me 一陪二十的赌注啊！
google says “Accompany the bet of twenty!” but im dubious. Please clarify folks!

Comment: 陪 is a typo. Try "一賠二十"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一赔（not 陪）二十的赌注啊 means ***odds of 20-1!***.

Answer (score 2):

一賠二十 means that when you use `N` dollars to bet. If you win you get `20N` dollars. If you lose, you lose `N` dollars.

In this example, 的 show that something before 的(一赔二十) is used to describe another thing after 的(赌注).

賭注 means gamble.

啊 is audible sound that show your emotion.

Reference: [Baidu知道 一赔二十是什么意思？](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/652909953836857845.html) [教育部重編國語辭典修訂本 啊](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000010251) [維基百科 漢語助詞](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E)

Comment: To be more precise, 赌注 means _wager_, not _gamble_.

Comment: @trisc thanks you. Nice, fix but I use bet.

Comment: [`A` dollars ] looks like 'a dollar'.  I suggest  use (N) instead. - "when you use (N) dollars to bet,  you will get 20(N) dollars  if you win, or  lose (N) dollars  if you lose

Comment: @Tang Ho fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Others' answers are completely correct.

To be precise from a more gambling point of view, 一赔二十 can mean either bet 1 get 20 back in total, or bet 1 get 20 as profit plus your initial bet (ie 21 in total). You may need to ask for clarification if you are considering putting millions on it.